# Calling class method from other class (PHP)

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

I realize this is a common question and I have tried resolving it myself, but after following instructions from other answers I can't get it to work. So, this is the issue - I need to call a method from the class ClassOne in ClassTwo. So I did this:

```
class ClassOne{
    public function methOne($par1,$par2){
        mysql_query("insert into ps_loyalty_events (customer_id,event_id) values ('$par1','$par2') ") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}

class ClassTwo{
    private $customer;    //initialize $customer in the constructor, to be defined as an instance of ClassOne() class and used as $this->customer

    function __construct() {
        $this->customer = new ClassOne();
    }

    public function methTwo(){
        //some stuff here
        $this->customer->methOne(6,10);    //6,10 - randomly chosen parameters, irrelevant
        //some more stuff here, this doesn't get executed at all
    }
}
```

The priblem is not in ClassOne or the method methOne() because calling them directly from a regular PHP file in the following manner works:

```
$customer = new ClassOne();
$customer->methOne(6,10);
```

However, when I call it from the ClassTwo method, it does nothing - it just stops the execution of that function. Using try-catch doesn't seem to output anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is `ClassTwo::methTwo` `static`? Are you aware of how `static` methods work?

Comment: Because I am blind. Yes, I'm aware, and I've removed the static. It still doesn't work however, so my question remains.

Comment: No error output? On command line or in the log files, when executed under a http server?

Comment: your code works fine for me. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e072ac804d6a240a9b1facf3407a1e1e3b97423c

Comment: @arkascha No error output whatsoever, anywhere. Just stops execution.

Comment: @robert Em, sorry, but that sounds unlikely. Might it be that error reporting is suppressed or you check the wrong logfile? Sorry, don't get that wrong. Not saying you don't know your stuff. But we all do such mistakes now and then. And a script does not simply vanish in thin air... And some debug output all around the commands to see how far you get...

Comment: The code you show doesn't do anything as is, but assuming you instantiate `ClassTwo` and call the method of the instance, it should work fine as is. If you have actual code which does not work, we need to see that actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `methTwo` is static. When you call a static method of a class, that class is not instantiated into an object, and therefore it doesn't have the `$this->customer` property.

Unless there is a reason for the static method, you can change `methoTwo`:

```
public function methTwo(){
```

Edit: now that you have fixed that: what makes you think it isn't working? You don't do anything in `methOne`.

The code given is fine, see this [Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/AEF80xeJ) of it working. That means there's some other code that we can't see that's causing the problem.

Comment: I've changed it, still doesn't work. The `static` was a leftover from my experimenting with the code earlier.

Comment: Well obviously, the real function does something. I just removed the content for the question because that part isn't relevant here - it's been tested outside of the class context.

Comment: @Prisoner The code has been updated. The query works when the method is called outside of ClassTwo.

Comment: @robert add a `die('test');` or something like that as the first line in the method to see if it's actually being called. Also check your error log.

Comment: @MrCode My bad, there's an error message now. Smarty was suppressing it. The error is: `Fatal error: Cannot access private property ClassTwo::$customer` - but changing $customer to 'public doesn't change anything.

Comment: That error can only occurr if you try to access the customer property from outside of ClassTwo, or from a class that derives from ClassTwo. In other words you must be accessing `customer` from the wrong place. The code in the question doesn't have that problem, so your real code must be where the problem is.

Comment: Argh. The code is called through AJAX in Smarty, so you can imagine 100 things could be going wrong. I have to go now, I'll get back to this later...

Comment: The error should tell you the line number, it would be interesting to see that line. Also you said `public` doesn't resolve the error so that could suggest you are editing the wrong file/not being uploaded etc etc.

Comment: Public resolves the error when I call the code directly. When I call it through AJAX it still doesn't output anything. Sorry for the confusion, I'm getting very lost in all this.

Answer (score -1):

For simple solution, try to use extend classone in classtwo, so that all the method can user in classtwo by default

```
class class_two extends class_one
```

By above all the method of class one will be accessed into class two and can easily use that also. try it

Comment: Inheritance should only be used when it is logical to do so, not as a patch to fix an underlying problem that is not understood. FYI I didn't downvote..

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure that would work but I'm trying to fix the issue, not mask it.

Comment: Posted. Once again, it does work outside the ClassTwo context, it's a simple MySQL query.